# Is there a more robust way to implement program flows dependent upon String values which are wildcards?

Tags: java

In my program, a user can pass 4 possible dates. 3/31, 6/30, 9/30 and 12/31.
However, the user may request data for any *year*. For example, they can ask for 6/30/15, or 6/30/88, or 6/30/16.

However, there are only two possible flows which my program can take. The rule is simple enough, and it is as follows:

If the requested date begins with a 3/31 or 9/30, then take flow #1.

If the requested date begins with a 6/30 or 12/31, then take flow #2.

I could have hardcoded this but since there are years involved, we cannot do this. Also, I know that we can't use *regular expressions* with switch statements.

My Code:

I wrote the following code in which I am first converting the variable reportDate into a String. Then, I use an if statement to determine whether the passed date was either "6/30/*" or "12/31. If so, I will add a method in the if condition to do something with that date. In the *else* portion, I will assume that the passed date must be "3/31/*" or "9/30/*"

```
        String requestedDate = Util.dateTimeToShortString(reportDate);

        if (requestedDate.matches("6/30/.*") | requestedDate.matches("12/31/.*")) {
            String twoQuartersBackDate = requestedDate;
        }
        String oneQuarterBackDate = requestedDate;
```

I'm not very comfortable with how this code is assuming flow #1, based on whether it finds a match on the *if* condition. There must be a better way to do this. Ideally, I would like to make it so that it would only accept dates from the 4 scenarios (quarters) I mentioned. Can anyone help me make this code more robust? I feel like it's amateurish at this point. Thank you.

Comment: Use `else if`? Also, `requestedDate.matches("(6/30|12/31)/.*")`.

Answer (score 0):

Two tips that I picked up:

1. The || operator would be more suited (efficient) in this case as we only need to determine if the first condition is true.
2. Since regular expressions can be slower to compute, using "startsWith" would be an ideal approach.

example:

```
if (requestedDate.startsWith("6/30/") | requestedDate.startsWith("12/31/")) {
```